# How to run multiple threads concurrently in Python3.4? And how does the Grid Layout Manager handle the controls?

Tags: multithreading, python-3.x, python-multithreading

```
def udp_communication_loop():
    global state
    global countdown_val
    global countdown
    _socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
    _socket.bind(("", 1200))
    while 1:
        received_message = ""
        received_message, addr = _socket.recvfrom(1024)
        received_message = str(received_message)
        if received_message != "":
            if received_message.find("Start") != -1:
                if(state == None):
                    state = 12
                    countdown_val = int(received_message[7:-1])
                countdown = 1
                cd_thread = threading.Thread(target=start_countdown())
                cd_thread.daemon = True
                cd_thread.start()
            if received_message.find("Stop") != -1
                countdown = -1
```

This is the function I start as a new thread from the main program which listens for UDP packages and starts or stops a timer displayed on GUI depending on the message.

If the UDP package contains the message "Start" it starts the countdown in a new thread.

```
def start_countdown():
global countdown
global countdown_val
while(countdown != -1):
    global state
    if state == 11:
        Label(root, text="AB", fg="red", relief=RIDGE,font=("Arial", 100)).grid(row=1, column=0, sticky="nsew")
        Label(root, text="CD", relief=RIDGE,font=("Arial", 100)).grid(row=1, column=1, sticky="nsew")
        state = 12
    elif state == 12:
        Label(root, text="AB", fg="red", relief=RIDGE,font=("Arial", 100)).grid(row=1, column=0, sticky="nsew")
        Label(root, text="CD", relief=RIDGE,font=("Arial", 100)).grid(row=1, column=1, sticky="nsew")
        state = 21
    elif state == 21:
        Label(root, text="CD",  fg="red", relief=RIDGE,font=("Arial", 100)).grid(row=1, column=1, sticky="nsew")
        Label(root, text="AB", relief=RIDGE,font=("Arial", 100)).grid(row=1, column=0, sticky="nsew")
        state = 22
    elif state == 22:
        Label(root, text="CD",  fg="red", relief=RIDGE,font=("Arial", 100)).grid(row=1, column=1, sticky="nsew")
        Label(root, text="AB", relief=RIDGE,font=("Arial", 100)).grid(row=1, column=0, sticky="nsew")
        state = 11
    cd2 = countdown_val
    print("Test before while ",countdown)
    while(cd2 >= 0) and (countdown != -1):
        print("test")

        Label(root, text=cd2, relief=RIDGE, font=("Arial", 250)).grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=2, sticky="nsew")
        print(cd2)
        cd2 = cd2-1
        if(cd2 == -1):
            countdown = -1
        time.sleep(1)
```

This functions counts down until it reaches 0 and as long as global countdown variable is different than -1.

Here is my problem : I give the Start signal and the countdown starts. Then while counting down I send the Stop signal but the timer doesn't stop. I tried printing the messages in the udp_communication_loop but it only prints the message after the countdown finishes which makes me think my two threads aren't running concurrently. I want to keep listening for UDP packages even while counting down. How to achieve this?

Another question related to the same program is about how the Grid Layout Manager works.

I declared a label called timer. It's the one that displays the timer. But I can't access it from my functions. I tried passing it as a parameter through threads and declaring it as a global variable but when I try timer.config(text=...), I get the error: "None type variable doesn't have a method called config". So instead of setting a new text for my already existing timer label I create a new one each time containing a different text at the same grid cell. What I've been wondering is that , does the grid layout destroy the previous labels contained at the same cell or just superpose them? And why can't I access my timer label in the first place?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
cd_thread = threading.Thread(target=start_countdown())
```

This line was the problem. Putting start_countdown() starts the function immediately before cd_thread.start.

```
cd_thread = threading.Thread(target=start_countdown)
```

This fixed my problem.

Just a syntaxe error on my part.